# Comparing fields of one table to other fields of another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function called `add_item()` which actually inserts values in a field `item_name` of temporary table called **`temp`** having fields `temp_id` and `item_name`. I have another table calleed **`item`** which consists of fields `item_id, item_name, price`. I have another table called **`quotation`** which consists of fields `q_id, item_id,item_name,price`.
Now I cant figure out how do i compare the `item_name` from `temp` to the field `item_name` from `item`. And then, insert the values of item in `quotation` table. Can anyone guide me please?
For example i have the following records in temp 
temp_id      item_name
1                           kit
2                          drill
3                        tester

and i have the following records in item:
id        item_name            price
1                  drill A                    100
2                   drill B                    354
3                  drill C                     743
4                  tester                      643
5                  cccc                         643

What I want to do is compare the item_name from temp table with that of table item.
after comparing i should insert these values in table quotation
quotation_id           searched_name item_name     price
1                                          kit                               not found          null
2                                         drill                               drill A              100
3                                         drill                               drill B              354
4                                        drill                               drill C               743
5                                       tester                            tester               643 
Can someone please guide me where to start?Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the comparison? What should the result be? What is the goal in the end? Comparing and inserting by itself is no big deal. How are these operations related to each other?

Comment: Using what? T-SQL, PL?? If you are going to compare you probably want to match by ID which doesn't seem to be in your temp table.

Comment: The goal is to compare the fields an generate an excel file with the item_name and price

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to refer to fields in multiple tables/databases in a single query, you use the '.' notation:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.value, table3.discount etc...
```

with the appropriate tables specified in your FROM and JOIN clauses. This can be extended to refer to fields in other databases entirely:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.value
FROM database1.table1, database2.table2
```

update:

```
INSERT INTO quotations
   SELECT item.item_name AS item_name, price
   FROM records
   LEFT JOIN temp ON item.item_name = temp.item_name;
```

should do the trick, assuming your quotations table has `item_name` and `price` fields.  This will pull out any records where the item_Name is the same in both tables, and insert the item_name and price into quotations.

Comment: Ni i need to compare field item_name from table 1 and item_name from table 2. and if they match i need to get the price of the item. Then i use the item_name and price and insert in in the quotation table to finally generate an excel file

Answer (score 0):

//select query for getting data from both tables

$get_data=mysql_query("SELECT *,temp.item_name AS searched, item.item_name AS response 
FROM temp JOIN item ON temp.item_name = item.item_name");

while($datas=mysql_fetch_array($get_data))
    {

```
          //inserting into quotation table
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO quotation SET 
                       searched_name='".$datas['searched']."',
                       item_name='".$datas['response']."',
                       price='".$datas['price']."' ");

}
```